# using glmer instead of lmer with transformed variables

Tags: probit, lme4-nlme

I am working with response time data. In our domain (eye-movements), there is an influential model (the LATER model by Carpenter) that makes clear predictions about how the reciprobit plot of the data would change under an experimental manipulation (either changing intercept with same slope, or changing slope with same intercept--either change has clear theoretical meaning). A reciprobit is formed by taking the empirical cumulative distribution of the reciprocal of the reaction times (1/RT), and Z scoring the percentile score of each observation. This yields straight lines when plotted (see e.g. red lines [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS3QW.jpg)).

I have such data for a bunch of subjects, which each did one of two conditions, and want to test whether the slope or the intercept changes between conditions. Before I do so, i want to think about what is the most appropriate way to fit this data in the first place. As after z-scoring the data forms a straight line with some noise, simple lmer should do the trick. However, due to the z transform, the most extreme datapoints would carry a lot of weight in such fits (indeed, we find that chopping off 5% of the data yields vastly different results, despite that, as you see in the figure, all data lay nicely along a line--thats entirely representative of all subjects). So is there perhaps a more appropriate way to do the test with glmer that avoids overweighting the extreme observations? Note that i am not looking to analyze reaction time differences, but specifically the change in slope or intercept in the reciprobit plot. I tried using glmer with percentile scores and `family=binomial(link = "probit")`, but this did not converge with message `(maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate`.

Here is the data from the left panel of the above plot, in case that helps. `prompt` is the 1/RT variable, and `cpn` the z-scored percentile:

```
structure(list(prompt = c(6.07162731746336, 6.04850724542573, 
5.77491779119695, 5.77140105426307, 5.74475318666047, 5.71990232875784, 
5.71885234231996, 5.7186598736582, 5.70931375680206, 5.66949668535962, 
5.64464676792393, 5.51012924035092, 5.50039688105864, 5.48580304245617, 
5.45357876862744, 5.43618236607085, 5.43058860632743, 5.41994771381777, 
5.415804942417, 5.40488350268993, 5.38547548017499, 5.37996777769352, 
5.36878082618339, 5.2423271414081, 5.2320164672025, 5.22486880940272, 
5.21948327520416, 5.20224110455795, 5.20178501102075, 5.1981044704829, 
5.17664629498367, 5.17006981026498, 5.16210244575449, 5.15605064076349, 
5.04759930588778, 5.02500528042602, 5.0193834977295, 5.01917169764546, 
5.0161461976049, 4.98501233437107, 4.97892602008876, 4.96629296345143, 
4.96142481285623, 4.94950699603201, 4.91805294951962, 4.87825008330593, 
4.84457661307788, 4.84087241389783, 4.8286507638839, 4.82425501894594, 
4.81412525821158, 4.81371835777037, 4.79176570843694, 4.79014136724913, 
4.78848528518754, 4.78798855363898, 4.77325055924048, 4.76675899783594, 
4.75748889242309, 4.75328237340901, 4.75143506436366, 4.74704176561709, 
4.74675332645689, 4.74611433494033, 4.63426685353793, 4.62778973229292, 
4.62771371040087, 4.62337654557847, 4.61746968789662, 4.61344335567581, 
4.59846256825597, 4.59659091706349, 4.55131758334545, 4.54114289724319, 
4.48260646469396, 4.48013965307894, 4.46630735480216, 4.46115588033228, 
4.43648001540454, 4.40889600267435, 4.30236199671268, 4.30004920755677, 
4.29099221978156, 4.27389322858193, 4.27110712611573, 4.25387092967637, 
4.24737376129172, 4.17525725695766, 4.16270143082465, 4.12363100589794, 
4.10451774951572, 4.07848666964074, 4.02400572252456, 3.99342346435377, 
3.98394873199183, 3.86901884216851, 3.86615571709562, 3.85965527214997, 
3.85572022845219, 3.73392673317608, 3.72111319742735, 3.63936418782736, 
3.62785823703989, 3.62265925754785, 3.58691815810904, 3.51493781405561, 
3.51483727760596, 3.43183865979926, 3.32606071249609, 3.08770914194077, 
2.84091946747443), cpn = c(-2.36856705926787, -2.10016549284447, 
-1.93028585605758, -1.80274309073919, -1.6991776601113, -1.61116916235268, 
-1.53412054435255, -1.46523379268552, -1.40267328999232, -1.34516663417664, 
-1.29179377582437, -1.24186679184332, -1.19485712407579, -1.15034938037601, 
-1.10801082046986, -1.06757052387814, -1.02880476200584, -0.99152647467733, 
-0.95557753794043, -0.92082297636838, -0.88714655901888, -0.85444739869599, 
-0.82263729107407, -0.79163860774337, -0.76138260968643, -0.73180808385962, 
-0.7028602309191, -0.67448975019608, -0.64665208107854, -0.61930676950878, 
-0.59241693538223, -0.56594882193286, -0.53987141220106, -0.51415610074453, 
-0.48877641111467, -0.46370775145718, -0.4389272020342, -0.41441332960008, 
-0.39014602446489, -0.36610635680057, -0.34227644932452, -0.31863936396438, 
-0.29517900048865, -0.27188000539926, -0.24872768963692, -0.22570795386016, 
-0.20280722023221, -0.18001236979271, -0.15731068461017, -0.13468979400892, 
-0.11213762424543, -0.08964235107576, -0.06719235471023, -0.04477617669552, 
-0.02238247829942, 0, 0.02238247829942, 0.04477617669552, 0.06719235471023, 
0.08964235107576, 0.11213762424543, 0.13468979400892, 0.15731068461017, 
0.1800123697927, 0.20280722023221, 0.22570795386016, 0.24872768963692, 
0.27188000539926, 0.29517900048865, 0.31863936396438, 0.34227644932452, 
0.36610635680057, 0.39014602446489, 0.41441332960008, 0.4389272020342, 
0.46370775145718, 0.48877641111467, 0.51415610074453, 0.53987141220106, 
0.56594882193286, 0.59241693538223, 0.61930676950878, 0.64665208107854, 
0.67448975019608, 0.7028602309191, 0.73180808385962, 0.76138260968643, 
0.79163860774337, 0.82263729107407, 0.85444739869599, 0.88714655901888, 
0.92082297636838, 0.95557753794043, 0.99152647467733, 1.02880476200584, 
1.06757052387814, 1.10801082046986, 1.15034938037601, 1.19485712407579, 
1.24186679184332, 1.29179377582437, 1.34516663417664, 1.40267328999232, 
1.46523379268552, 1.53412054435255, 1.61116916235268, 1.6991776601113, 
1.80274309073919, 1.93028585605758, 2.10016549284447, 2.36856705926787
)), .Names = c("prompt", "cpn"), row.names = 1632:1742, class = "data.frame")
```